# What connection (if any) is there in Australian slang between 'dinkum' and 'dink' (meaning a ride on bicycle handlebars)?

Tags: etymology, slang, australian-english, origin-unknown

In an answer to the recent question, [What is the American equivalent of a "backie"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/464436/what-is-the-american-equivalent-of-a-backie/464479?noredirect=1#comment1120971) site participant Chappo notes that in Australia the word *dink* is sometimes used as a noun to mean "a lift on a bicycle" and the verb *dink* can mean "carry a person on a bicycle" (both definitions provided by [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dink) online). OLD has this very brief source note:

> **Origin** 1930s: origin unknown.

A term familiar in Australian English but not widely used most other parts of the English-speaking world is *dinkum*.  G.A. Wilkes, *A Dictionary of Australian Colloquialisms* (1978) gives two entries for *dinkum*:

> **dinkum** *n.* 1 Work, toil: *obs.* {E. dial. OED 1891} [Citation from 1882 omitted.] 2 An Australian soldier in World War I: *obs.* [Citations from 1918 and 1919 omitted.]
>
> **dinkum** *a.* & *adv.* authentic, genuine, esp. in the expression 'fair dinkum' ('on the level') [Citations from 1894–1973 omitted.]

Jonathon Green, [*Cassell's Dictionary of Slang*](https://books.google.com/books?id=5GpLcC4a5fAC&pg=PA407&dq=%22dinkum%22+dink&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwis3tSF9b7dAhUBK3wKHVkhDT8Q6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=%22dinkum%22%20dink&f=false), second edition (2005), lists several meanings for *dinkum* in Australian slang (to much the same effect as Wilkes's definitions above) and three relevant meanings of *dink* in Australian slang:

> **dink** *n.*<sup>5</sup> {1930s+} (*Aus. juv.*) a lift on the crossbar of a bicycle (cf. BUNK v.<sup>5</sup>). {ety. unknown}
>
> ...
>
> **dink** *adj.* 1 {1900s–1930s} (*Aus.*) honest, genuine, trustworthy. {abbr. DINKUM adj.}
>
> ...
>
> **dink** *v.* (also **double-dink**) {1940s+} (*Aus. juv.*) to give anyone a lift on the crossbar of one's bicycle (cf. BUNK v.<sup>5</sup> {DINK n.<sup>5</sup>}

The entry for the verb *bunk* cited twice in the definitions above identifies it as a 1950s Australian slang term meaning "to carry someone on one's bicycle crossbar" and later a 1980s+ term meaning ""to travel without a fare, to get in (e.g. to a cinema) without a ticket."

My question is this:

> What evidence (if any) is there of a possible etymological link between *dink* (the bicycle ride) and the earlier *dinkum* (either in the adjective sense of "authentic or genuine" or in the noun sense of "work, toil")?

Comment: ***The story of ‘dinkum’*** : even dinkum  etymology appears to be obscure. The different theories suggested in the following informative extract  don’t seem to have any relation with dink. http://ozwords.org/?p=6840 - dink, as suggested here might come from   *perhaps  British dialect dink to dandle a baby* https://www.macquariedictionary.com.au/resources/aus/word/map/search/word/dink/Tasmania/

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/142592/whats-the-origin-of-dinkum

Comment: @user070221: I had completely forgotten about that earlier question regarding _dinkum_ (which I seem to have spent a fair bit of time working on just three months ago). Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Is _dinkum_ really not familiar outside AuE? I didn’t know the noun, but _fair dinkum_ is quite familiar to me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: As far as I know, it is unused in U.S. and Canadian English—and people here tend to have at most a vague idea that it's an Australian expression, like "G'day, mate" but with a less easily translatable meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a relevant clue about **dink** is that its earliest uses appeared to be the longer phrase **double-dink**, where the "double" refers to two people on the same bicycle.

The earliest citation in *GDoS* is in verb form from **1914** and uses "double dink":

> Motor Cyclist Takes Passenger On Carrier. Falls Off. Passenger Hurt, Law Stops **Double Dinking**. What To Do— See Dom Riley's Side Cars, £5 To £40.

- **1914**  [Aus]   *Hamilton Spectator* (Vic.) 27 July 5/2: [advert]

That the phrase originated as "double-dink" offers an alliterative clue as to why the slang "dink" caught on, although not a complete explanation.

A later *GDoS* citation offers several variants:

> **Double-dink**, to carry a second person on the top bar of a bicycle. It is also a noun. Exchangeable terms are **‘dink’**, **‘donk’**, and **‘double-bank’**, both as verbs and nouns.

- **1941**  [Aus]   *Baker Popular Dict. Aus. Sl.* 25

The variant "donk" is interesting, as the phrase "double-donkey" can also be found used to describe two people riding together on a bicycle or a horse.

[image]

- [**1927** *The Age* (Melbourne, Victoria, Australia) 29 Jul 7/6](https://www.newspapers.com/image/122851666/?terms=%22double%2Bdonkey%22) (paywall)

Of course, this instance of "double donkey" comes later than *GDoS*'s earliest citation of "double dink," but the context of the use suggests to me that perhaps riding "double donkey" was a slang term earlier than is recorded in print that I've been able to find.

---

Interestingly, this clipping from **1924** suggests that **double donk** was not only in use in the United States as well at such an early date with reference to riding an animal, but also that it appears to have been a relatively established expression:

> Remember when we used to ride **"double donk"** on the farm? Here is **"quadruple donk."**

[image]

- [**1924** - *Des Moines Tribune* (Des Moines, Iowa) 27 Aug 16/2](https://www.newspapers.com/image/323857794/?terms=%22double%2Bdonk%22) (paywall)

---

Based on this evidence, I'm inclined to speculate that "dink" meaning a ride on a bicycle is simply coincidental to "dinkum" as Australian slang.  It appears to have originated as an alliterative slang "double-dink," which may or may not have derived from the phrase "double donkey" which has a more obvious literal derivation.

Comment: Thanks for this excellent research! Your analysis seems very sound to me.